# Solr server not starting when using GraphDbAdminHandler.Getting ClassNotFoundException for ImmutableMap Class from CoreAdminHandler class

Tags: solr, graphdb

In solr.xml, I have added the following lines of code.

```
 <str name="adminHandler">com.ontotext.solr.handler.admin.GraphDBConnectorAdminHandler</str>
```

When I try starting the solr server, I get the following exception:

```
2019-03-16 16:49:15.624 ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.<clinit>(CoreAdminHandler.java:223)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:541)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:626)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createHandler(CoreContainer.java:1696)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:575)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:253)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:750)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 57 more
```

What should I do now?

I have all jars required and it gets loaded in the classloader, while my solr starts without custom admin handler.

I refered the following document to add graph db solr connector to automatically sync the data when added to graphdb

http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/solr-graphdb-connector.html

Comment: Can you tell me the versions you are using for Solr and GraphDB?

Answer (score 0):

Your missing class definition tells you that the class `com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap` is missing. This class is part of [Google's Guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

If you're using Maven or something similar you can add the dependency there, or if not, you can [download the jar for the regular JRE from mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/27.1-jre).

Comment: Hi MatsLindh Thanks or your Reply,

                         I have inclused the same JAR in my lib folder inside solr home and I can see that the cassloader loads the content of all the jar files in logs.
                         To add on, the solr starts when i point the admin handler to default admin handler i.e. CoreAdminHandler